# 'sa' password change in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ws-security

When I tried to connect (with the 'sa' login) to our SQL server, I got an error message about invalid password. I tried again and again, with the same result.
So, I reconnected to the SQL server in Windows authentication mode and reset the password of 'sa', but the question is whether somebody could remotely change the 'sa' password?
Thanks,

Ilan.

Comment: C'mon, everybody knows your password is 'Administrator' !

Comment: ;-) No, something you couldn't guess easily..

Comment: Is there anyone in your company that would benefit by changing the SA password? Can you elaborate on the server a little, is it external network (zomg internets!) facing, was the sa password `blank` or by any chance was it perhaps `Sony1`? How long was the password? Is there any chance that a previous employee would have had access to it? When do you know that the previous password worked? And lastly, who might have access to change the local administrators for a moment, change the SA password and then remove themselves from local admins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sa account's password can be changed remotely.  That is, if someone already knows the sa password, they can log in with it, execute "alter login [sa] with password 'new password'" and bada bing the password is changed.  Moreover, anyone with the alter any login permission on the server would be able to do the same.

Comment: It might be worth setting up an event notification on alter login then.  I'm not a fan of mystery password changes.  The problem is that it won't catch calls to (the deprecated) sp_password, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: you should consider who has access to change who has administrative privileges? check the eventlog (`eventvwr`) for your server as you should be able to see if someone logged into the system who might have access to change the local administrators for a moment

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the comment. I'll try to add an event notification you pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to reset your SA password through ssms:

1. Firstly Login with Windows Authentication where you don't need to enter any password.
2. Go to Security>Login inside the Object Explorer on left side
3. Right click on "sa", select "properties" option.
4. Then you need to enter the new "Password" and "Confirm Password" and click on "ok" button.
   [image]
5. Then right-click on the server name and select properties option
6. Select SQL server and Windows Authentication mode only.
   [image]
7. Click on "ok" .
8. Now restart the SQL Server(MSSQLServer) service.
9. And now try to login with username "sa" and new password in SQL server Authentication.